# Efficient band matrix storage

Tags: r, dataset, matrix, sparse-matrix, package

Is there an R package that sees a sparse matrix (i.e. many zero entries) such as a 4-by-4 matrix:

```
Q <- matrix(c(1,-1,0,0, -1,2,-1,0,  0,-1,2,-1, 0,0,-1,1), nrow=4); print(Q)
```

and store (and operate) it as a 4-by-2 matrix:

```
Q.band <- matrix(c(1,2,2,1, -1,-1,-1,0), nrow=4); print(Q.band)
```

Since the zero entries are not needed, and due to symmetry we need not store the non-zero off-diagonal entries twice.

I investigated the R packages Matrix and spam. They were useful but did not do exactly as the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dsCMatrix` from the `Matrix` package:

> The dsCMatrix class is a class of symmetric, sparse numeric matrices
>   in the compressed, column-oriented format.

So in your case:

```
library(Matrix)
as(Q, "dsCMatrix")
```

This will store only 7 elements

```
 length(as(Q, "dsCMatrix")@x)
 [1] 7
```

To get your matrix `Q.band`, you can do the following for example.

```
matrix(c(as(Q, "dsCMatrix")@x,0),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   -1
[2,]    2   -1
[3,]    2   -1
[4,]    1    0
```